# How to reformat/transform data query results before displaying them in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, bindingsource

I am using the `DataGridView` component to quickly and easily display read-only SQL query results to the user. I have it working as desired, but I have to wonder if I'm doing things the "right" way. It's a complicated component after all, and I am completely new to SQL access and data binding in .NET.

The MSDN help suggests using a `BindingSource` object as the intermediary, so I've come up with the following code (which seems to work just fine):

```
mBindingSource.DataSource = null;
mBindingSource.Clear();

using (SqlDataReader query = GetQuery())
{
  if ((query != null) && (query.HasRows))
  {
    mBindingSource.DataSource = query;
    CDataGrid.DataSource = mBindingSource;
  }
}
```

However, I want to reformat some of this "raw" data. For example, some of the values are stored as `int` or `byte` types in the underlying tables, but they actually represent various `enum` values. Currently I am using the following code to perform the desired transformation (inspired by [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1cc356h%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)):

```
private void CDataGrid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs args)
{
  DataGridViewColumn column = CDataGrid.Columns[args.ColumnIndex];
  switch (column.Name)
  {
    case FieldNameProductID:
    case FieldNameVersionID:
      int? x = args.Value as int?;
      ProductCode code = (ProductCode)(x ?? 0);
      args.Value = code.ToString();
      break;

    case FieldNameProductType:
      byte? y = args.Value as byte?;
      ProductType type = (ProductType)(y ?? 0);
      args.Value = type.ToString();
      break;
  }
}
```

Is this the proper way to do things? The reason I ask is because it seemed as if the `BindingSource` object is designed partially to perform such types of transformations. The documentation is hard to navigate, however, and I have yet to find a good example of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the correct way of doing it. The CellFormatting event captures the data before it is being rendered so it can be altered.